# How does one use a VM as a gateway to the internet for a host-only VM?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a VM server with a NAT interface and a host-only interface. I have a VM client which has a host-only interface. Is there a way to reach the internet as well as other VM’s on the same host-only network from client through server? I need the server VM to act as a gateway to the internet and the internal network. I’ve tried adding static routes but I can’t get it to work. Is such a thing feasible before I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server VM will need to have special software/services/daemons installed and configured on it to make it work.  What software you use depends greatly on what OS is installed on the server VM.

For example, if the server VM is running a Windows server OS, you might start with installing the Routing and Remote Access Service (RRAS) role.  However, you might be looking at a double NAT scenario at that point.  It has been a while since I've played with that.  But anyway... double NAT won't be a problem if you're doing this just as a learning exercise (which I assume you are since there's no practical reason not to just setup a NAT network connection on the client VM).  However, if you're doing this for some other reason as a permanent solution that you'll use day in and day out, double NAT can cause some interesting routing issues.

Comment: It's a learning exercise for a networking course, they're both Linux machines but now I know where start to look at least.

Comment: Just got it: http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/

Comment: I've never done it with Linux, but I'm guessing it will be the same stack that's used on DD-WRT routers.  I honestly don't know what all is required, but I know from tweaking my own DD-WRT setup that you're probably looking at iptables and maybe some special modules to allow NAT.  (or that... looks like our comments crossed paths - glad you got it figured out)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. I assume you are using linux or unix like servers.

The VM with 2 legs (lets call it a NATVM) will serve as a NAT for the other VMs. Lets assume the NAT VM has one leg (eth0) on the NAT network and the other (eth1) on the host network.

All the other VMs should set the NATVMs eth1 IP address to be their gateway address. Then within the NATVM, use the following instructions to setup the NAT.

http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html